# C# Url.Action parameters - Sub application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, url, subapplication

I am working on sub application related changes in web app. My web application is optimized to run with or without virtual directory. For that, I met with a condition that checked whether the incoming URL is having **"/"** or **"/{subapplicationname}/"**

To check this case I made a condition like below,

`HttpContext.Request.Url.AbsolutePath == Url.Action("/", "/")`

Without Subapplication: "/" == "/"

With Subapplication: "/applicationname/" == "/applicationname/"

Well actually, both cases (with and without sub application) passed.

And my doubt is whether `Url.Action("/", "/")` syntax is correct? or else going for HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppVirtualPath is optimal one?

I have searched over internet and didn't find `Url.Action("/", "/")` scenario.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use the default routes for your MVC, like `Url.Action("Index", "Home")` or just `Url.Action("", "")` will do too

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion! @mylee